# I can't connect my phone to my WiFi network

Tags: nokia-lumia-920, wifi

I've tried EVERYTHING to connect my phone to my WiFi again and it keeps saying "your phone can't connect to the WiFi network", it doesn't say try again later anymore.

Comment: Did you try to restart your WiFi router? Other devices are connecting to the WiFi network without any kind of issues? What kind of protection is setup on the network (WPA, WEP, free etc.)? Please add more details to your question if possible, it'll be easier to help you.

Comment: this is exactly what happened for me i changed my router and now it's OK.

Answer (score 2):

Try these things:

- Reboot your phone and try to reconnect
- Perform a soft-reset (you wont loose any data). To do so hold your vol-down and powerbutton of your phone for 10 seconds while its powered on. It will shutdown and perform the softreset.
- If the above points didn't work go to your system settings and do a complete reset (you'll loose all data so think about doing a backup before).

Comment: Before suggesting an hard reset, let's see if the problem is located elsewhere instead of the phone.